# Simulate concatenated file using hard link?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, aforge, hardlink

I have multiple parts of a single file which I want a 3rd party c++/c# plugin to read as a single file. Basically, when the plugin file reader gets to the end of one file-part, I want it to continue to the next one.

(For anyone interested, the plugin is Aforge.Net FFMpeg, and I am trying to import VOB files)

It looks like quite a task to reprogram the plugin. An alternative solution is to copy the file parts to a concatenated file, but this is slow because I am dealing with many GBs of data.

Is it possible to use a file system hard link to point to multiple files? Or is there some other way to 'fake' a concatenated file? Using command line FFMpeg I can use 'type' to live stream a concatenate file in, but I can't figure out how to achieve this in c# with this plugin.

I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

A hard link can only reference one I-node, so a hard link won't help. A FIFO, or named pipe, however, will. In a UNIX shell, you can do:

```
$ mkfifo catenated
$ cat a b c >catenated &
```

A program that reads from the file "catenated" will now get all three files (a, b and c) concatenated together. Once the data from all three files have been read, the "cat" program will terminate. Microsoft Windows also has such features (see [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Windows)).

Note that a pipe is not seekable. If the program reading the concatenated data tries to seek, it will fail. If the concatenation needs to be seekable, something more complicated (virtual filesystem? FUSE?) needs to be used.

Comment: Pipe works with FFMPEG, but I can't figure out how to use a pipe in c#. The plugin expects a path string as input.

Comment: Ok. Read up a little. Named Pipes are supported in .Net 3.5 - great. Now I need to figure out a way of turning a named pipe into a path string of some kind!

Comment: There is another problem, though, this will cat only once. You'd need an additional program or whatnot which loops over the cat command. _And_ you cannot read more than once at the same time.

Comment: Read once should be fine, I think.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, a hard link points to only one file.

You have the added complexity that your app is a third party app... The only solution I see would be to write a dynamic object overriding the file methods *only for a particular path* so that, for instance, `read()` would start with the first file, then go on to the second after having finished the third etc. Uh. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This might be best handled with [avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page). It's been years since I used it, but IIRC, you can use it to script video file concatenation such that they appear as a single file. I can't remember the details, but the script files behave as if they are a video file and can be used as a source in most video editing applications.